# Avoid unused and undefined variable in playbook

Tags: ansible, ansible-2.x

I have following data in a variable file

```
data: [
    {
        service: "ServiceName",
        var2: "file/path/value",
        var3: "{{ check_var }}",
    }, {
        service: "ServiceName",
        var2: "file/path/value",
        var3: "{{ check_var }}",
    }
]
```

I have two playbooks which require the same data. However one playbook does not require **var3**.

```
- debug: msg="{{ item['service'] }} uses - {{ item['var2'] }}"
with_items: "{{ data }}"
```

This gives error - **"'check_var' is undefined"**.
**TRIED:**
I don't want to populate the playbook with bad standards and use
**when: check_var is undefined**
Or use false dummy data in playbook's vars atrribute. Is there any way around this while maintaining standards. Also the actual data is quite huge so I don't want to repeat it twice for each playbook.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Ansible data has to be assigned to hosts not to playbooks.

You have to create two host groups. Those hosts, who needs just two variables go into the first group. And those hosts which need 3 variables go into both groups. You can include the hosts of the first group in the second group.

Then you create two group var files. In the first you put 2 variables and in the second the 3rd variable.

By this each host gets the right amount of information. Playbook 1 uses 3 variables and playbook 2 uses just 2 variables.

**Update:** Minimal example

```
$ diff -N -r none .
diff -N -r none/check_var.yaml ./check_var.yaml
0a1,4
> ---
> - hosts: localhost
>   tasks:
>     - debug: var=check_var
diff -N -r none/group_vars/myhosts.yaml ./group_vars/myhosts.yaml
0a1
> check_var: "Hello World!"
diff -N -r none/inventory ./inventory
0a1,2
> [myhosts]
> localhost
```

```
$ ansible-playbook -i inventory check_var.yaml

PLAY [localhost] ***************************************************************************

TASK [Gathering Facts] *********************************************************************
ok: [localhost]

TASK [debug] *******************************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => {
    "check_var": "Hello World!"
}

PLAY RECAP *********************************************************************************
localhost                  : ok=2    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=0
```

Comment: Hi, I am using "extra-vars" to pass the value of host and "check_vars" to the playbook. The main objective of the playbooks is to fetch logs or change other parameters on specified hosts machines. 2 playbooks are performing different tasks but on the same hosts. Hence only one of them needs additional variable. I will move the "Data" variable to group vars but the error will persist.

Comment: If you define a host, put the host in a group, define the variable `check_var` in the group vars file, then the variable will never be undefined for the host, whatever play-book you are running.